# Wordpress - Listing custom posts using Ajax load more plugin is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have use **ajax load more** plugin in my wordpress website. The problem is that its display list of custom post, after sometime it is not showing any post from the same post type on same page.

Comment: Have you checked your number of posts with the post that loaded with ajax load more. I might be not showing since all the post were displayed and it doesn't found any post thereafter.

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli I have 107 posts on my website. And the problem occurs on first time load I mean when I refresh the page I set 6 posts are already displayed but that 6 posts are sometimes loaded with page load and sometimes not.

Comment: I think i have to test the plugin that you have used currently. If not you can have a custom ajax load more would be better. 
If you need help on custom then i can help you around. Also, could be please have a link of the plugin that you are using?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli, I don't want to create custom functionality for this, since it is time-consuming and there is already plugin for that. Please check the below link.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/